# AS3 method call to javascript + NO SERVER COMMUNICATION

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, externalinterface

Code below is my jscript, I believe I don't have any error on integrating the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
params.allownetworking = "all";
var attributes = {};
attributes.id = "map-moa";
swfobject.embedSWF("./video/map.swf?v=1.3", "map-moa", "1560", "980", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>

$(".goto-path").on("click",function(){
    // alert("goto booth #"+$(this).data('booth_id'));
    sendTextToAS3(); // call Flash (AS3) Method
});

function sendTextToAS3(){
    var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
    var flash = (isIE) ? window["map-moa"] : document["map-moa"];
    console.log(flash)
    try{
    flash.sampleMethod();
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

I am having an error as undefined method yet the function are properly declared in my as3 class.

```
public function Main():void { ExternalInterface.addCallback("sampleMethod", callbackID); }
public function callbackID():void { trace(this, "TEST"); }
```

Comment: Your code looks ok to me, this is sometimes finicky... have you tried different browsers? IE/Chrome have their own versions of Flash and you might get different results. How does "no server communication" at the end of your question relate to the problem?

Comment: i just thought if there is need to get it LIVE or into the cloud in order to use the ExternalInterface of AS3 sir

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that might be related but it depends on how you are accessing the web page that contains the Flash app. Are you serving the web page from a web server on your computer, or just opening the page from a file on disk? There are different security constraints when you do this. If you are running the SWF from disk, you might try adding the directory that contains the SWF to this Flash Player [global settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) (in the "Always trust files in these locations" box.

Comment: i'm just running the file from the local disk not to any web server service.

Comment: i just came out for a work around that i really need a web server in order to communicate the actionscript to javascript using ExternalInterface.

Comment: Try the Flash Player settings that I linked to above. That might do the trick... it's been so long since I worked w/Flash that I don't remember if it will help.